# Yesod and dynamic Bootstrap/jQuery form

Tags: jquery, forms, yesod

I work with an existing form built with Bootstrap. But this form contains `<input>`s dynamically added with jQuery. So user can add any number of inputs before submitting the form.

I know that the names of these inputs forms like `attr1`, `attr2`, `attr3` and so on. But I cannot run it like this:

```
event <- runInputPost $ NewEvent <$> iopt textField "attr1"
                                 <*> iopt textField "attr2"
                                 <*> iopt textField "attr3"
```

because these inputs created dynamically. So I need extract, well, some list of these `textField`s from the form. Is it possible? I never worked with dynamic forms, so I need any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is runRequestBody: http://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-2.7/yesod-core-1.4.9.1/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:runRequestBody

Comment: Thanks, Michael! You helped me as usually.